# Regex url block specified word AND optimization

Tags: regex, postgresql, pattern-matching, sql-like

The simplified code:

```
SELECT 'ok' WHERE '/articles/new/' ~ '^/articles/(?!new)([\w-]+)/$';
```

Examples, what I want:

```
'/articles/new/' => ''
'/articles/new-york/' => 'ok'
'/articles/other-string/' => 'ok'
```

And, what's wrong:

```
'/articles/new/' => ''
'/articles/new-york/' => '' /* Wrong */
'/articles/other-string/' => 'ok'
```

So, how can I block ONLY the word?

### Optimization

In PostgreSQL database, I have a table (`page`), and it has got columns `path, title, file, regex_path etc.`

The values in column `path` look like this:

```
/
/articles/
/articles/:category-code/
/articles/:category-code/:article-code/
/articles/:category-code/:article-code/edit/
/articles/new/
/members/
/members/:username/
```

`:` means it's a parameter (PHP gets the name and content based on regex_path – the first version)

From outside (PHP) the database gets a value (URL). Examples:

```
/ /* Main page */
/articles/ /* List all article */
/articles/it/ /* List articles in IT category */
/articles/it/ipad-mini-2/  /* Article */
/articles/it/ipad-mini-2/edit/ /* Edit article */
/articles/new/ /* New article */
/members/ /* Member list */
/members/someone/ /* Member datasheet */
```

How can I select the right row, where the value (URL) matches with the path (the fastest way, without regex)?

#### Example

**In:** `/articles/it/ipad-mini-2/`

**Out:** the row, where `path` is: `/articles/:category-code/:article-code/`

Comment: It's unclear whether you want to block only `'/articles/new/'` or all `'/articles/new/.*'`. It's also unclear whether a leading '/articles/' is required.

Comment: The updated question is too broad now, and on the other hand does not provide necessary details.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: I modified it again, now?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: it is complete, work with the first solution. `$ sql = "SELECT * FROM page WHERE :rurl ~ regex_path"; $params = [':rurl' => cc::$data['req_path']];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is faster:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl 
WHERE  txt LIKE '/articles/%'
AND    txt <>   '/articles/new/';  -- only exclude this exact string
```

*Take everything that starts with '/articles/', but exclude '/articles/new/'*

Or, to exclude the whole branch:

```
...
AND    txt NOT LIKE  '/articles/new/%';
```

Either includes '/articles/new-york/' because, here, 'new' is not immediately followed by '/'.

#### Performance test

**Regular expressions are typically more expensive** than `LIKE` or `=` or `<>`.
Test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. Or `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, TIMING OFF)` to suppress noise. See:

- [Get execution time of PostgreSQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063402/get-execution-time-of-postgresql-query/9065976#9065976)

I ran a test to confirm my claim. It's ~ 10 - 20 x faster than the regular expression.

```
'^/articles(?!/new/)/([\w-]+)/$' -- Daniel's solution
```

.. which should be simplified to (a bit faster):

```
'^/articles/(?!new/)[\w-]+/$'
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3932d69e7671548bd2ab31c020adfb27)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/acb73/1)</sub>

Explanation for the 2nd regexp:

`^` ... start of string
`/articles/` ... literal match
`(?!new/)` ... [negative lookahead](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-BRACKET-EXPRESSIONS) matches where no string 'new/' follows
`[\w-]` ...  [bracket expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-BRACKET-EXPRESSIONS) containing the [class shorthand](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE) `\w` plus the dash `-`
`+` ... 1 or more times
`/` ... literal match
`$` ... end of string

Comment: The `path` row values:
`/
/articles/
/articles/:category-code/
/articles/:category-code/:article-code/
/articles/:category-code/:article-code/edit/
/articles/new/
/members/
/members/:username/`
Without regex, how can I select the right row?

Comment: @bsz: I added a bit to my answer. I suppose you edit your question to clarify the requirements.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter `'^/articles(?!/new/)/([\w-]+)/$'`  I don't understand the fourth /;  I also don't understand [\w-], Can you explain these two?

Comment: @JianHe: I clarified above.

Answer (score 1):

You were close, I changed the negated look ahead to be more specific.  It fails to match only if the look ahead finds `/new/`.

```
^/articles(?!/new/)/([\w-]+)/$
```

The Results

```
/articles/new
/articles/new/
/articles/new-york/ => OK
/articles/other-string/ => OK
/articles/notnew/ => OK
```

Test is here:

### [REY](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/8fbab5il)