# How to benchmark a set of PostgreSQL queries?

Tags: postgresql, benchmarking, common-table-expression, sqlperformance

I have a **batch** of SQL benchmark queries that I would like to execute and compute their timing. I **do not** want to obtain the execution plan with the command EXECUTE ANALYZE.

Based on the approach suggested here [Get execution time of PostgreSQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063402/get-execution-time-of-postgresql-query)
I have written a procedure that contains for each query the following code

```
-------------------------
Query = 'Q1';
StartTime := clock_timestamp();

PERFORM <** Query 1 goes here **>

EndTime := clock_timestamp();
Duration := 1000 * ( extract(epoch from EndTime) - extract(epoch from StartTime) );
INSERT INTO execution_tests VALUES (Query, StartTime, EndTime, Duration);
-------------------------
```

I use PERFORM instead of SELECT to execute the query and discard the result.

That works for simple queries, but I have many queries that have a WITH clause. According to the manual

> For WITH queries, use PERFORM and then place the query in parentheses.
>   (In this case, the query can only return one row.)

However, all the WITH queries I need to benchmark return multiple rows.

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

What about something like

```
do $$
declare
  p json;
  your_query text := 'select pg_sleep(1.1)';
  t interval;
begin
  execute 'explain (analyse, format json) ' || your_query into p;
  raise info '%', p;
  t := make_interval(secs := ((p->0->>'Planning Time')::float + (p->0->>'Execution Time')::float)/1000);
  raise info '%', t;
end $$;
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks ! How to remove the CONTEXT messages after RAISE INFO ? I have tried   ALTER DATABASE test3 SET log_error_verbosity = TERSE; but didn't work. P.S. I am executing on pgAdmin

Comment: @EstebanZimanyi Not sure what you mean. It is just an example. As I understood, you want to store execution time into the table...

Comment: Indeed, but it would also be nice (not necessarily in this particular example) to remove all messages such as "CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test_queries() line 262 at RAISE" each time a message is displayed on the screen when executing long scripts such as benchmarking a long batch of queries with different scale factors. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: @EstebanZimanyi The problem is that I have no such additions to messages here. So no any ideas.

Comment: @EstebanZimanyi It seems that it is `psql` feature: https://www.depesz.com/2008/07/12/suppressing-context-lines-in-psql/