# How to measure time difference in milliseconds in a function?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, timing, supabase

I would like to calculate the difference between the starting time (variable of type `timestamptz`) and the `NOW()` moment when my function finishes.

```
select * from _get_date_diff_ms(NOW(), NOW())
```

Using supabase.io with PG 13.3, I get this error message:

> ```
> operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone - double precision"
> ```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _get_date_diff_ms(p_begin_time timestamptz, p_end_time timestamptz)
RETURNS int AS
$$
    BEGIN
        RETURN ROUND ((
            EXTRACT (EPOCH FROM p_begin_time -
            EXTRACT (EPOCH FROM p_end_time)
        ) * 1000));
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Does `ROUND(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM p_end_time - p_begin_time) *1000)` work? Remember: now() will always have the same value in a transaction: the start time of it. See also [EXTRACT, date_part](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)

Comment: You are right. I am getting the start and end time inside the SAME function (p/lpgsql), I tried clock_timestamp() and now() and they give this DOUBLE PRECISION error

Comment: What's the idiomatic way of calculating the time spent by the PL/PGSQL function (in milliseconds)? From the BEGIN (start_time) until the RETURN (end_time)? I want to store this value into a column in another TABLE called (search_history). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone - double precision
> ```

That's just because of wrong parentheses. You meant to write:

```sql
        RETURN ROUND ((
            EXTRACT (EPOCH FROM p_begin_time) -    -- !
            EXTRACT (EPOCH FROM p_end_time)
        ) * 1000);
```

But the whole approach is broken. It's been pointed out by now that `now()` is a stable value within a Postgres transaction. See:

- [Difference between now() and current_timestamp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63549/3684)

Moreover, for your expressed purpose, it makes no sense to pass a "starting time" to begin with.

- Either you mean the starting time of the transaction: then use `now()` anywhere in the function.
- Or you mean the starting time of the function: then use `clock_timestamp()` at the start of the function.

Assuming the latter, I suggest:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public._get_date_diff_ms() -- no parameter
 RETURNS numeric  -- !
 LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _start_ts timestamptz := clock_timestamp();  -- !
BEGIN
   PERFORM pg_sleep(1);   --  do something here (1 sec example)
   RETURN round(1000 * EXTRACT(epoch FROM clock_timestamp() - _start_ts), 3);
END                                                                                
$func$;
```

Call:

```sql
test=> SELECT public._get_date_diff_ms();
 _get_date_diff_ms 
-------------------
          1003.440
```

I return `numeric` with 3 fractional digits instead of `integer` to capture microseconds. Else, it would just report 0 for many fast operations.

See:

- [Get execution time of PostgreSQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063402/get-execution-time-of-postgresql-query/9065976#9065976)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public._get_date_diff_ms(p_begin_time timestamp with time zone)
 RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    BEGIN
        RETURN round((EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM clock_timestamp() - p_begin_time ) * 1000));
    END;                                                                                
$function$
;

 select _get_date_diff_ms(now() - interval '.5 sec');
 _get_date_diff_ms 
-------------------
              500
```

I threw a negative interval in the function call to actually get a diff. For what the the various time functions do see [Current time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT).