# EXPLAIN ANALYZE not working with ALTER TABLE

Tags: sql, postgresql, explain

I'm trying to alter the type of a column from a table but I also want to know how long it takes to alter the table. I therefore combined:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE
```

command with:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name ALTER COLUMN col_name TYPE new_type;
```

So I did:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN my_column TYPE text;
```

But I get the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ALTER"
LINE 1: EXPLAIN ANALYSE ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN my_column...
                        ^
```

But when I `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` with a `SELECT` it has no problem. I.e.:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 300;
```

I must be missing something really simple but I'm not seeing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The manual for `EXPLAIN`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html)

> Any `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `VALUES`, `EXECUTE`, `DECLARE`, `CREATE TABLE AS`, or `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW AS` statement, whose execution plan you wish to see.

`ALTER TABLE` is not covered.

Comment: Thank you, should have checked the docs for EXPLAIN, is there a way for me to time how long it would take to alter a column then?

Comment: Are you using psql?  Just turn timing on: `\timing on`.

Comment: Thanks, I just saw that from https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/269251/how-can-i-see-execution-time-of-an-alter-table-statement

Comment: @Mark: Ways to get the execution time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9065976/939860