# How to analyze the performance of a loop with postgres?

Tags: postgresql, timing, postgresql-performance

I have a script.sh which executes 1 script.sql.

It will look for the data in a data table.
I have a loop and in this one I have other loops which will look for information in the data table and insert them into the correct tables.

At the beginning of my project my script ran in 45 minutes.

I made several modifications and I am at 8 p.m. I have a problem somewhere without really understanding (I put the indexes unless I forgot some).

How can I, in Postgres, analyze each 'sub loop' to know the execution time in order to understand why it has become long?

example:

```
begin 
for query
loop
   -- loop 2
   begin
   for query
   [...]
   end loop;
-> raise notice 'duration or explanation';
   end;

-- loop 3
   begin
   for query
   [...]
   end loop;
-> raise notice 'duration or explanation';
   end;
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Are you looking for [query plan analysis](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PL/pgSQL functions are black boxes to the query planner. Nested statements are not covered separately in `EXPLAIN` output. The additional module [**`auto_explain`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html) lets you log execution plans *including* nested statements.
You must be superuser.

See:

- [EXPLAIN ANALYZE shows no details for queries inside a plpgsql function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/84496/3684)
- [Get query plan for SQL statement nested in a PL/pgSQL function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/23355/3684)

Basics about timing:

- [Get execution time of PostgreSQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063402/get-execution-time-of-postgresql-query/9065976#9065976)

Answer (score 1):

You can see the run time for the whole query in pgAdmin or by using the EXPLAIN before your query. This is probably not enought to know how to improve the query

To measure runtime, you can use

```
raise notice '%', clock_timestamp();
```

inside plpgsql function.

Sometimes this can be useful but I don't think this is the way to improve runtime.
You should be aware of the parameters that have the main impact the runtime of a query:

1. The number of queries.
2. The amount of data returned from the query
3. The amount of data in the database

Reducing any amount will improve the runtime.
Usually, one query is much faster than many queries in a loop. You can create chunks just by combining the query string with ; between the individual queries, it will be faster. this is because all of this will be in one tracsaction. and open and close of the traction takes time.

Comment: ok thank you on the other hand I don't understand I did load' 'auto_explain' but with pgadmin4 I don't see the log. how to see the log with the duration?

Comment: In pgAdmin if you run the query with query tool. under the query editor, You have the tabs: Data Output, Explain, Messages, Notifications. the Total runtime shown in Messages tab

Comment: OK, thanks. And in a script.sql file, it is not possible to create a .log file with the trace of the explain? thank you