# Split time range into range of whole days and remaining hours before / after

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series

In Postgres, given a collection of date ranges like:

| meter_id | device_id | start_at | end_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| meter1 | device1 | 2020-01-02 10:30 | 2025-01-02 14:00 |
| meter2 | device1 | 2020-01-02 10:30 | 2020-01-02 11:30 |
| meter3 | device1 | 2020-01-02 10:30 | 2020-01-03 11:30 |

I want to bucket the ranges into:

- a range for the whole days
- a range for the hours / mins before the whole days
- a range for the hours / mins after the whole days
- if the range already fits into a whole day bucket, then just leave it alone

So the above would end up as:

| meter_id | device_id | start_at | end_at | remark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| meter1 | device1 | **2020-01-02 10:30** | 2020-01-03 00:00 | hours at start of 1st row |
| meter1 | device1 | 2020-01-03 00:00 | 2025-01-02 00:00 | whole days from 1st row |
| meter1 | device1 | 2025-01-02 00:00 | **2025-01-02 14:00** | hours at end of 1st row |
| meter2 | device1 | **2020-01-02 10:30** | **2020-01-02 11:30** | 2nd row left alone |
| meter3 | device1 | **2020-01-02 10:30** | 2020-01-03 00:00 | hours at start of 3rd row |
| meter3 | device1 | 2020-01-03 00:00 | **2020-01-03 11:30** | hours at end of 3rd row |

I have written something which works but it's pretty complex and ugly.

**Is there a simpler way of doing this?**

#### Table and data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS metering_ranges (
    metering_point_id text NOT NULL,
    device_id text NOT NULL,
    start_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    end_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO metering_ranges( metering_point_id, device_id,  start_at, end_at)
VALUES 
    ('meter1', 'device1', '2020-01-02 10:30:00', '2025-01-02 14:00:00'),
    ('meter2', 'device1', '2020-01-02 10:30:00', '2020-01-02 11:30:00'),
    ('meter3', 'device1', '2020-01-02 10:30:00', '2020-01-03 11:30:00');
```

#### Existing (complicated) solution

```sql
with 

ranges_with_whole_days as (
    SELECT
        metering_point_id,
        device_id,
        start_at,
        date_trunc('day', start_at) + interval '1 d' as start_at_next_whole_day,
        date_trunc('day', end_at) as end_at_whole_day,
        end_at
    FROM
        metering_ranges
),

ranges as (
    SELECT
        metering_point_id,
        device_id,
        start_at,
        CASE
            WHEN start_at_next_whole_day <= end_at_whole_day THEN start_at_next_whole_day ELSE NULL
        END as start_at_next_day,
        CASE 
            WHEN end_at_whole_day >= start_at_next_whole_day THEN end_at_whole_day ELSE NULL
        END as end_at_prev_day,
        end_at
    FROM
        ranges_with_whole_days
),

ranges_bucketed AS (
    -- get hours before whole day
    SELECT metering_point_id, device_id, start_at, start_at_next_day as end_at
    FROM ranges m
    WHERE start_at_next_day IS NOT NULL
    
    UNION
    
    -- get whole day period
    SELECT metering_point_id, device_id, start_at_next_day as start_at, end_at_prev_day as end_at
    FROM  ranges m
    WHERE start_at_next_day IS NOT NULL AND end_at_prev_day IS NOT NULL AND start_at_next_day != end_at_prev_day
    
    UNION
    
    -- get hours after whole day
    SELECT metering_point_id, device_id, end_at_prev_day as start_at, end_at
    FROM ranges m
    WHERE end_at_prev_day IS NOT NULL
    
    UNION
    
    -- get existing record if it fits within a day
    SELECT  metering_point_id,  device_id, start_at, end_at
    FROM ranges m
    WHERE start_at_next_day IS NULL AND end_at_prev_day IS NULL
) 

SELECT *
FROM ranges_bucketed
ORDER BY metering_point_id, device_id, start_at
```

Comment: Your data type is `timestamp(0) with time zone`. So you **must** define the time zone that's setting day boundaries first. (Also, the sample data displays plain `timestamp [without time zone]` literals, which contradicts the table definition.) Or can we assume `timestamp` instead? Your version of Postgres? (`SELECT version();`)

Comment: Yes lets assume timestamp. I initially created the table with pgAdmin and overlooked this odd column definition.  Postgres 15.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming data type `timestamp` (Going with your sample data, not the contradicting table definition that shows `timestamptz`.) Else, you have to do more. See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

#### 1. Split all ranges at midnight, keep full days merged

As made clear by your comments. (Also, in line with your sample row for 'meter3'.)

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *
        , CASE WHEN start_at::time = '0:0' THEN start_at
               ELSE date_trunc('day', start_at) + interval '1 day' END AS start_day
        , date_trunc('day', end_at) AS end_day
   FROM   metering_ranges
   )
-- nothing to split
SELECT metering_point_id, device_id, start_at, end_at
FROM   cte
WHERE  end_day < start_day

-- split core days
UNION ALL
SELECT metering_point_id, device_id, start_day, end_day
FROM   cte
WHERE  end_day > start_day
-- add leading range
UNION ALL
SELECT metering_point_id, device_id, start_at, start_day
FROM   cte
WHERE  end_day >= start_day
AND    start_at::time > '0:0'
-- add trailing range
UNION ALL
SELECT metering_point_id, device_id, end_day, end_at
FROM   cte
WHERE  end_day >= start_day
AND    end_at::time > '0:0'
ORDER  BY 1,2,3;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9Wfr5BpF)

Use `UNION ALL`, not `UNION`. Faster.
Also, you can append `ORDER BY` to a `UNION` query once at the end. That applies to the whole result set.

#### 2. Only break out ranges of full days

My initial interpretation. (Maybe the more common use case?)

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *
        , CASE WHEN start_at::time = '0:0' THEN start_at
               ELSE date_trunc('day', start_at) + interval '1 day' END AS start_day
        , date_trunc('day', end_at) AS end_day
   FROM   metering_ranges
   )
-- nothing to split
SELECT metering_point_id, device_id, start_at, end_at
FROM   cte
WHERE  end_day <= start_day
-- split core days
UNION ALL
SELECT metering_point_id, device_id, start_day, end_day
FROM   cte
WHERE  end_day > start_day
-- add leading range
UNION ALL
SELECT metering_point_id, device_id, start_at, start_day
FROM   cte
WHERE  end_day > start_day
AND    start_at::time <> '0:0'
-- add trailing range
UNION ALL
SELECT metering_point_id, device_id, end_day, end_at
FROM   cte
WHERE  end_day > start_day
AND    end_at::time <> '0:0'
ORDER  BY 1,2,3;
```

The **only difference**: ranges without nested full days are still split at midnight. I.e. Ranges starting after 00:00 and ending before 24:00 of the next day. The fiddle demonstrates it.

Related:

- [Are results from UNION ALL clauses always appended in order?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/316864/3684)

##### Variants for case *2.* with multirange type

These won't work right off the bat for case *1.*, as ranges are only split when whole days are extracted. Doesn't fit your sample row for 'meter3'.

Requires **Postgres 14** or later. We can use the new `anymultirange - anymultirange` → `anymultirange` operator. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-range.html#MULTIRANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE)

> Computes the difference of the multiranges.

We can then `unnest()` the resulting multirange to get remaining fractions.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *
        , CASE WHEN start_at::time = '0:0' THEN start_at
               ELSE date_trunc('day', start_at) + interval '1 day' END AS start_day
        , date_trunc('day', end_at) AS end_day
   FROM   metering_ranges
   )
-- nothing to split
SELECT metering_point_id, device_id, start_at, end_at
FROM   cte
WHERE  end_day <= start_day

-- nested full days to split
UNION ALL
SELECT metering_point_id, device_id, x.*
FROM   cte
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   VALUES (start_day, end_day)
   UNION ALL
   SELECT lower(rest), upper(rest)
   FROM   unnest(tsrange(start_at, end_at)::tsmultirange
               - tsrange(start_day, end_day)::tsmultirange) rest
   ) x
WHERE  end_day > start_day
ORDER  BY 1,2,3;
```

Or even shorter without CTE and with a `LEFT JOIN LATERAL`:

```sql
SELECT c.metering_point_id, c.device_id
     , COALESCE(x.start_at, c.start_at) AS start_at
     , COALESCE(x.end_at, c.end_at) AS end_at
FROM  (
   SELECT *
        , CASE WHEN start_at::time = '0:0' THEN start_at
               ELSE date_trunc('day', start_at) + interval '1 day' END AS start_day
        , date_trunc('day', end_at) AS end_day
   FROM   metering_ranges
   ) c
LEFT   JOIN  LATERAL (
   VALUES (start_day, end_day)
   UNION ALL
   SELECT lower(rest), upper(rest)
   FROM   unnest(tsrange(start_at, end_at)::tsmultirange
               - tsrange(start_day, end_day)::tsmultirange) rest
   WHERE  c.end_day > c.start_day
   ) x(start_at, end_at) ON c.end_day > c.start_day
ORDER  BY 1,2,3;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9Wfr5BpF)

But constructing, computing and then unnesting multiranges adds considerable overhead. Not sure if this level of sophistication can compete with the more "brute force" queries.

Comment: @PeteG I would be interested how the variants perform with your data. Can you give feedback on the performance of each? Here are some techniques to measure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9065976/939860

Comment: Solution 1 works great for me and is fairly easy to understand.  I didn't look into performance compared to other approach, as you say it should be pretty efficient due to the 'brute force' nature of it.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The date ranges can be added by a `left join` of the prepared time series (via `union all`) back onto the original table. The join condition specifies valid ranges:

```sql
select distinct r.meter_id, r.device_id, coalesce(t.a, r.start_at), coalesce(t.b, r.end_at)
from metering_ranges r left join lateral (
   select r.meter_id id, r.start_at a, date(r.start_at) + make_interval(days => (r.end_at != date(r.end_at))::int) b
   union all
   select r.meter_id id, date(r.start_at) + make_interval(days => (r.end_at != date(r.end_at))::int) a, date(r.end_at) b
   union all
   select r.meter_id id, date(r.end_at) a, r.end_at
) t on greatest(t.a, t.b) <= r.end_at and t.a < t.b and t.a >= r.start_at 
order by r.meter_id
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wOogrm06)

Comment: Some splits occur that shouldn't. See: https://dbfiddle.uk/2WmeXJO7

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I think you are correct for `meter5`, however, one of the rows in the test table contains the `OP`s original data for `meter3, device1`: `('meter3', 'device1', '2020-01-02 10:30', '2020-01-03 11:30')`, but your code produces one split for it, `meter3 device1 2020-01-02 10:30:00 2020-01-03 11:30:00`, in contrast to the OP's desired output, which should contain two splits for `meter3`.

Comment: Good point. Though it would seem the sample result contradicts the expressed objective by splitting fractional days. The question should be consolidated in either direction.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I agree. In any case, thank you for the feedback, I updated my post

Comment: Thanks for all the efforts! Is the ambiguity coming from this statement? 'if the range already fits into a day then just leave it alone'?.  I've tried to make it clear in the question that I mean a whole day 'bucket'.  Struggling a bit with the correct terminology. The output in the sample result is what I desire.

Comment: i.e. a range that crosses over 2 days but spans might night should produce 2 rows (meter3).  A range which already starts and ends at might night should be 1 row (meter5)

Comment: @PeteG: I adapted my answer to this clarified objective.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of tinkering, came up with this and wanted to share but it may be a more ugly solution though.

```
select *
from 
(
select metering_point_id, device_id, 
start_at, 
case when date(start_at)=date(end_at) then end_at else date(start_at+INTERVAL '1 day') end end_at
from  metering_ranges
union
select metering_point_id, device_id, 
case when date(start_at)=date(end_at) then null else date(start_at+INTERVAL '1 day') end, 
date(end_at)
from  metering_ranges
union
select metering_point_id, device_id, 
case when date(start_at)=date(end_at) then null else date(end_at) end, 
end_at
from  metering_ranges
) t 
where t.start_at is not null and t.start_at!=t.end_at
order by metering_point_id
```