Adding missing commas to strings matching a given pattern
I am trying to add a comma and a space to my strings. Here are some examples:

{ELEPHANT:1, FENNEC_FOX:1NAKED_MOLE:1URCHIN:2}
{DUNG_BEETLE:12URCHIN:1}
{DUNG_BEETLE:1FENNEC_FOX:1URCHIN:2}

Notice the inconsistent lack of ", ". I would like to outcome to be

{ELEPHANT:1, FENNEC_FOX:1, NAKED_MOLE:1, URCHIN:2}
{DUNG_BEETLE:1, URCHIN:1}
{DUNG_BEETLE:1, FENNEC_FOX:1, URCHIN:2}

I think I need to use REGEXP_REPLACE(my_string, ':[0-9]+[a-z_A-Z]', replacement). But I'm not quite sure how to make replacement be the colon and whatever the number is, a comma and a space, and whatever the matching letter is.

Your regex is fine, although you can simplify it by using \d in place of [0-9] and \w in place of [a-z_A-Z]. You then need to use capturing groups to save the matched text and insert it into the replacement string:
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(my_string, '(:\d+)(\w)', '\1, \2', 'g')
FROM my_table

Output:
{ELEPHANT:1, FENNEC_FOX:1, NAKED_MOLE:1, URCHIN:2}
{DUNG_BEETLE:12, URCHIN:1}
{DUNG_BEETLE:1, FENNEC_FOX:1, URCHIN:2}

If you're trying to convert this into valid JSON, you'll need a second step to enclose the keys in double quotes:
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(my_string, '(:\d+)(\w)', '\1, \2', 'g'), '(\w+):', '"\1":', 'g')
FROM my_table

Output:
{"ELEPHANT":1, "FENNEC_FOX":1, "NAKED_MOLE":1, "URCHIN":2}
{"DUNG_BEETLE":12, "URCHIN":1}
{"DUNG_BEETLE":1, "FENNEC_FOX":1, "URCHIN":2}

Demo on dbfiddle.uk
Note that although \w includes digits as well as letters and _, it's OK to use it in this regex because the greedy \d+ will consume all digits before attempting to match \w.

This expression gets your desired result (fastest in a quick test with 100k rows):
regexp_replace(my_string, '(:\d+)(?=[a-zA-Z])', '\1, ', 'g')

Core features are the positive lookahead (?=[a-zA-Z]) and the 4th parameter 'g'.
Working with a positive lookbehind is slower for this - as hinted by Nick.
regexp_replace(my_string, '(?<=:\d+)([a-zA-Z])', ', \1', 'g')

fiddle
Related answer with more explanation:

After 5 occurrences, replace all forward slashes with a hyphen


Using a (variable length) lookbehind is far less efficient than just matching the : and digits (and including them in the replacement) as it requires checking every letter in the string to be matched to see if it is preceded by that pattern.

See for example https://regex101.com/r/0HQMke/1 which takes almost 3 times as many steps as https://regex101.com/r/LQJVON/1

@Nick: Thanks for pointing out. A quick test confirmed that your variant is ~ twice as fast. I added a version with a positive lookahead, that's even faster than that. BTW,  [a-zA-Z] is faster than \w  (and correct for the task)  because the latter includes digits (and more).

\w is fine here because OP's regex includes _, and \d+ being greedy will consume all digits before attempting to match \w.

@Nick: I am not saying it's wrong. It's a bit slower. My note " (and correct for the task)" is meant to point out that [a-zA-Z] is not wrong.

I'm curious as to how you tested that?

@Nick I created a table with 100k rows of the given pattern and ran the test shown here (chapter 4.): https://stackoverflow.com/a/9065976/939860

Cool. Lots of good stuff in that answer :)
