Filter table on jsonb column containing a value a given number of times
How can I filter rows where an object in a jsonb column contains a specific value a given number of times? My jsonb column contains something like:
{
  "fri": "from_home",
  "mon": "from_home",
  "sat": "dont_work",
  "sun": "dont_work",
  "thu": "commute",
  "tue": "from_home",
  "wed": "commute"
}

I want to get all rows where this column has, say, 3 days set to "from_home". I've been looking through the various pg functions for JSON but I'm just getting lost as to what would be the best fit.

jsonb_path_query returns 1 row per match. Then count and filter:
SELECT *
FROM   tbl t
WHERE  (SELECT count(*) FROM jsonb_path_query(t.js, '$.* ? (@ == "from_home")')) = 3;

fiddle
Unless you can (additionally and selectively!) filter by a non-aggregated key or key/value pair, an index won't help.
As so often, switching off JIT improves performance for me:
SET jit = off;

Also, jjanes' query is substantially faster with jsonb_each_text() (even if not as fast as the above).
...
WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM jsonb_each_text(js) WHERE value = 'from_home') = 3;


Amazing this is perfect thank you! Do you know how this would compare performance wise with jjanes answer as that works as well?

@PaReeOhNos A quick test shows this to be about twice as fast as Jeff's variant with jsonb_each(). But much of the difference can be equalized by using jsonb_each_text() instead. Please test in your productive environment and let us know your results. How to test? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9065976/939860

Amazing thank you, I'll do some playing around if I get time to see what's going to be the most performant option

you can use jsonb_each_text function (https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json-functions/postgresql-jsonb_each_text/)
select count(*), id from 
(select id, key, value from table_source, jsonb_each_text(col_json) sub1
where value='from_home' group by id having count(*)>3;


Just do a sub-select with jsonb_each.
 with t as (select '{
  "fri": "from_home",
  "mon": "from_home",
  "sat": "dont_work",
  "sun": "dont_work",
  "thu": "commute",
  "tue": "from_home",
  "wed": "commute"
}'::jsonb j)
select * from t where (select count(*) from jsonb_each(j) where value='"from_home"')=3;

You could wrap it into a function if you wanted to make it look a bit cleaner, which would also enable you to make an index on it.

Amazing this is perfect thank you! Do you know how this would compare performance wise with Erwin Brandstetter answer as that works as well?
